# TDD for Event system

Tags: 2011, event-system

We are planning to perform Test Driven Development for Event System. Is there any framework or methodology that allows Test Driven Development?

Comment: I haven't seen anything specific to testing the event system from the community, though there are plenty of ways to confirm your event system code is doing what's expected. Easiest would be to simply use the CMS. What exactly are you trying to build?

Comment: Correction, Nick has addressed the topic as prompted by this question. :-) Though this still feels a bit wide open, I'm upvoting since it solicits responses, examples, and explanations. A bit more context on why Test Driven Development is required and what's being built would help get better answers, though.

Comment: The requirement for TDD came from guidelines that Enterprise Architects released saying that each code that is written should be at-least 80% code coverage through unit testing.

Answer (score 6):

A very intrigueing question (assuming you're after being able to use something like NUnit for the Event System).  I've written a blog post to address it:
http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/test-driven-development-for-the-tridion-event-system-is-it-worth-it

Answer (score 2):

Amazing to see that there are thoughts on TDD for Event System.
To answer your question, Event System is just another .NET code and you should be able to use any of the .NET based TDD tool like -

- NUnit
- MSUnit
- xUnit.NET
- csUnit etc. and there are many more

A comparison of few of them you can see [HERE](http://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Comparisons&referringTitle=Home)

However, I am wondering (as also mentioned in the Nickoli's Blog) what all you are implementing in the Event System that requires you for TDD and as Nickoli is also wondering - What all you will gain out of it?

I would suggest - you should re-assess your need and ask yourself if you are doing over-engineering by using TDD - If your answer is No, use any of the tool above.
If subsequently, you face any specific issue for TDD in event system, post that here and we will be happy to help.

Comment: To be specific, we have event system that does the automatic publishing digital assets from different places based on event it is triggered from. While trying to mock the Tridion API object using MoQ, I am having really hard time. For e.g. Component object, I want to mock object of Component object however unable to do. Once mock of Component object is created then I want to override save method.